# Where can I change the size and form of the Robot at the SBPL Lattice Planner

Tags: ros, planner, robot, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can I change the size and form of the Robot at the SBPL Lattice Planner?

I would like that the Robot looks more like a car, and not so circle-formed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165486/where-can-i-change-the-size-and-form-of-the-robot-at-the-sbpl-lattice-planner/) by [Ico](https://answers.ros.org/users/17981/ico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set the robot footprint as described [here in the navigation stack robot setup tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Costmap_Configuration_.28local_costmap.29_.26_.28global_costmap.29). If you look at the [actual code in sbpl_lattice_planner.cpp](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_experimental/blob/groovy-devel/sbpl_lattice_planner/src/sbpl_lattice_planner.cpp#L139), you´ll see that the footprint provided by the costmap is used there (lines 117 and 139).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ico](https://answers.ros.org/users/17981/ico/) on 2014-05-16**:
Yes, I found that, but I don't really understand that. How could I change the code so that the robot would be rectangle?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-05-16**:
to have a rectangular robot that is 30x20cm you´d use

footprint: [[-0.15, 0.1], [0.15, 0.1], [0.15, -0.1], [-0.15, -0.1]]

(Haven´t tried that myself, but the idea should be clear)